# split data from long string text then update each data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a bit complex stored procedure in ms sql database. My main focus is take a input of long string text then split the data by characters and update that data where matching. In detail: `DataString` is the input long text string which will contain value like bellow example. 
 
`'-'` is separator between name of data type and its value
`','` is separator between two different kind of value
`':'` is separator between two set of data, each set of data separates by `:`
Now can u tell me how can i grab each data from long string and insert them where matching? Ask question if you still need to know something. Thanks in advance

Example of long text string:

```
ASIN-NsQf8,type-0,Price-7,IsPrime-1:ASIN-fD5tsQ,type-1,Price-13,IsPrime-0:ASIN-tvQtsu,type-1,Price-14,IsPrime-1
```

The Unfinished SQL Code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.lk_UpdateMatchingDataOfThirdparty 
@DataString VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE ThirdPartyData SET Price = @value_get_from_string, IsPrime = @value_get_from_string, DateChecked = GETDATE()
    WHERE ASIN = '@value_get_from_string' AND type = '@value_get_from_string';
END
GO
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: MS SQL management studio current version

Comment: @jarlh `dbo` and `VARCHAR(MAX)` smell of SQL Server.  What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Yes it is MS SQL Server 2017 express edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately string_split() does NOT return a sequence number.  So if you are open to a an alternative split/parse function which is also performant.

**Note:** I made assumptions with the try_convert() portion

**Example**

```
Declare @DataString varchar(max) = 'ASIN-NsQf8,type-0,Price-7,IsPrime-1:ASIN-fD5tsQ,type-1,Price-13,IsPrime-0:ASIN-tvQtsu,type-1,Price-14,IsPrime-1'

UPDATE A 
   SET Price       = B.Price
     , IsPrime     = B.IsPrime
     , DateChecked = GETDATE()
 From  ThirdPartyData A
 Join  (
        Select [ASIN]   =replace(max(case when B.RetVal Like 'ASIN-%' then B.RetVal end),'ASIN-','')
              ,[Type]   =try_convert(int,replace(max(case when B.RetVal Like 'type-%' then B.RetVal end),'type-',''))
              ,[Price]  =try_convert(money,replace(max(case when B.RetVal Like 'price-%' then B.RetVal end),'price-',''))
              ,[IsPrime]=try_convert(bit,replace(max(case when B.RetVal Like 'IsPrime-%' then B.RetVal end),'IsPrime-',''))
         From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](@DataString,':') A
         Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,',') B
         Group By A.RetSeq
       ) B 
   on  A.[ASIN]=B.[ASIN] and A.[Type]=B.[Type]
```

**If it Helps with the Visualization, the sub-query Returns**

```
ASIN    Type    Price   IsPrime
tvQtsu  1       14.00   1
NsQf8   0       7.00    1
fD5tsQ  1       13.00   0
```

**The TVF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
```

> **EDIT: If you want the 2016+ `string_split()` approach**

```
Select [ASIN]   =replace(max(case when Value Like 'ASIN-%' then Value end),'ASIN-','')
      ,[Type]   =try_convert(int,replace(max(case when Value Like 'type-%' then Value end),'type-',''))
      ,[Price]  =try_convert(money,replace(max(case when Value Like 'price-%' then Value end),'price-',''))
      ,[IsPrime]=try_convert(bit,replace(max(case when Value Like 'IsPrime-%' then Value end),'IsPrime-',''))
 From (
       Select A.RN
             ,B.*
        From ( Select RN=Row_Number() over (Order by (select null)),* from string_split(@DataString,':') ) A
        Cross Apply string_split(A.Value,',') B
      ) A
 Group By RN
```

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid object name 'dbo.tvf-Str-Parse'.

Comment: @johnCogdle You need to add the function provided

Comment: @johnCogdle Added the sub-query for a 2016+ approach

Comment: Yes this works! but can u tell me why i am getting message like- Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @johnCogdle You can either add SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF or extend the case with ... ELSE '' ...   for example   ... then B.RetVal else '' end